# How to refresh tab bar content upon reopening the app from home screen? (iOS / Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

for all of my view controller.m I have the majority of my code in:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

So, each time I switch between tab bars all of the info in each view refreshes. (which is good!) Although, when I open the app from the home screen the tab won't update...I have to switch to another tab and back again to get it to load.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sign up for a notifications to handle it. Register each tab for the notification and a method to handle it. Then just perform your viewDidAppear. It works like a charm.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(becomeActive:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil];
}

-(void)becomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // only respond if the selected tab is our current tab
    if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) { // Tab 1 is 0 index, Tab 2 is 1, etc 
        [self viewDidAppear:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: where would the first part of this code go? everything in the view controller.m?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer. I would put it in your viewDidLoad for each view controller. Then just set the selectedIndex based on which tab you are on.

Comment: When i am doing this than first time when i launch app, notificationnot firing but when i press home button again and lunch then i can see updated data on that tab. can you please suggest how to handle this so my data load at first time when i launch app from app icon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can invoke all your refreshing code in

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
```

this method is in your AppDelegate.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this in the view controller's m file:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```